# Transaction Management outside Data Access Layer

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

Data Access Layer is not responsible for `transaction management` am I correct? I have these DAO implementations: `HibernateDAO and SqlDAO`. If I will choose Hibernate and handle its transaction management at above layer, when I switch to SQL then I will change every single transaction management made by the `Hibernate to SQL`? This is bad right? What strategy will I gonna use in this case? TIA.

Comment: Is SqlDAO based off any tool? Or is it plain JDBC calls?

Comment: Hello. Right now I haven't write anything inside the SqlDAO but I guess it would be just plain JDBC calls. What flexibility would you suggest so that the above layer that will handle transactions will not be dependent whether the DAO is using Hibernate, JDBC or other implementations? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked on transactions outside of spring and JTA. Spring offers a transactions across several different platforms using [transactions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).  You may want to check that out.

Also, I've seen JTA transactions work on ejb, Hibernate and Jms messages, but not sure if it will work for jdbc and hibernate, more on hibernate transactions [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-jta).